# Trying to create a cronjob in django using faust

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, faust

I'm trying to create a cronjob in django using faust. If I create a simple cronjob printing somethin' on screen it works, but if I try to use some ORM thing it doesn't.

```
@sync_to_async
def get_products():
    return Product.objects.filter(active=True)


@app.crontab('* * * * *')
async def run_very_minute():
    product = await get_products()
    print(product)
```

I also tried to do like this:

```
@app.crontab('* * * * *')
async def run_very_minute():
    products = await sync_to_async(list)(Product.objects.filter(active=True))
    print(product)
```